# How to remove a space before a dot?

Tags: javascript, space, uppercase

I try to add a dot in the middle of sentence, before a capital letter.
I tried this:

```
function correctSentences(str){
  s = str.replace(/([A-Z])/g,'. $1').trim();
 return s;
}
correctSentences("  avi loves pizza Dani loves cola  ");
```

The output is:

```
"avi loves pizza . Dani loves cola"
```

how can i remove the space before the dot?
thank you!

Comment: What will you do when there are capitals in your sentence that are not the start of a sentence? Like "when will David come", or "here I am", ... and many other cases?

Comment: good question... this is just an exercise..

Comment: If it's just an exercise, then you grade/rate the answers below on this specific requirement, not the other edge cases which you are now seeing pop up.  If you need a more general solution, then you would probably need to write some kind of parser, or use a library which already exists; but regex alone is likely not the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Add `\s` in regex

```js
function correctSentences(str){
  s = str.replace(/(\s[A-Z])/g,'.$1').trim();
 return s;
}

console.log(correctSentences("  avi loves pizza Dani loves cola  "));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this version:

```js
function correctSentences(str) {
    return str.replace(/\s+(?=[A-Z])/g, '.  ').trim();
}

var input = "  avi loves pizza Dani loves cola  ";
var output = correctSentences(input);
console.log(input + "\n" + output);
```

The regex logic here says to:

```regex
\s+        match one or more whitespace characters
(?=[A-Z])  then assert (but do not consume) that what follows is a capital letter
```

We replace with dot, to end the previous sentence, followed by two spaces, to separate from the start of the next sentence.

Comment: thank's. I add a dot before 'Dani' and the output include two dots...

Comment: Not sure what this comment is supposed to be saying.  Care to elaborate?

Comment: I mean that this solution doesn't prevents to add an additional . if there's already a . exists.

Comment: @yosii84 You have many, many edge cases which my answer (and the other answers given here) won't cover.  Regex is not a panacea for correcting the grammar and punctuation in your text.

Answer (score 0):

I propose:

```js
function correctSentences(str){
  return str.replace(/(?=\b\s+[A-Z])/g, '.').trim();
}
const result = correctSentences("  avi loves pizza. Bob loves pizza Dani loves cola  "); 

console.log(result);
```

Also it prevents to add an additional `.` if there's already a `.` exists.